# Understanding the CSS descendant selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

> The following selector represents a p element that is a descendant of
> an li element; the li element must be the child of an ol element; the
> ol element must be a descendant of a div.

```
div ol>li p
```

What is a `descendant` in the above terminology?

Let's say the example of `child` is like this

```
<ol>
    <li>entry</li>
</ol>
```

Then is this html matches to the above selector?

```
<div><span>mixtures<span/><div/>
<ol>
    <li>sugar</li>
    <li>milk</li>
</ol>
<p>Stir both mixtures together.</p>
```

Comment: Any space in a selector refers to a descendant element. So, _"Then is this html matches to the above selector?"_ No, because it fails off the bat with `div ol` because the `ol` isn't a descendant of the div, it's a sibling

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <p>sugar</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>milk</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Think of your great grandmother (`div`), your grandmother (`ol`), your mother (`li`) and you (`p`).

Your grandmother, your mother and you are all descendants of your great grandmother.

But only your grandmother is a child of your great grandmother. Only your mother is a child of your grandmother. And only you are a child of your mother.

Back to HTML/CSS terms, all nested elements are descendants of the parent, but only the first level of descendants can be the children.

---

> The following selector represents a `p` element that is a descendant of an `li` element; the li element must be the child of an `ol` element; the ol element must be a descendant of a div.

> div ol>li p

Let's break it down:

> The following selector represents a `p` element that is a descendant of an `li` element

Use the descendant combinator (  ). All descendants (not just the children) are being targeted.

> the li element must be the child of an `ol` element

Use the child combinator (`>`). Only the first level descendants (the children) are being targeted.

> the ol element must be a descendant of a div

Use the descendant combinator (  ).

See [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors) for more details.